# Attribute table not changing when using Mosaic on rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, attribute-table, mosaic

I'm looking to "merge" 2 rasters together. One is the original base land cover raster with 6 classifications/land use classes. The other is a raster from converted polygons that are essentially "updates" or "improvements" on one particular class.

I thought mosaic would do the trick, and it did. My new raster has my new updated classifications, BUT, when I go into the attribute table, the COUNT for each class remains the same! For example, if 'agriculture' changed to the new updated forest, then my COUNT for agriculture should go up, while that for forest should go down.

Is there another way to "merge"/"combine" these two raster layers that updates the attribute table along with it?

I'm also planning on adding a new class to this raster. Would mosaic also work for that?

I also tried raster calculator but that seemed to do the same thing as combine, outputting only the areas of the new updated raster (so AND/intercept, while I need OR/union).

Comment: Use raster calculator conditional, something like Con(IsNull("improvements"),"original","improvements")